# How to update SSRS textbox when database table value/string changes

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

In my report I have a text box , which is reading data from database table using below query:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[Table] ORDER BY [ID] DESC
```

The strange thing is, for the 1st time its reading/reandering the content from the table and displaying.
 However, when the database table value is updated, the updated value/string is NOT getting papulated/rendered in the text box.

Note: From "data set properties" -> "query designer" , I'm getting updated string. I'm unclear, why the updated table string NOT getting updated/rendered in the text box.

Is there anything , am I missing?

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below Image report1.rdl.data file, I am sure in your project workspace there is similar file. just delete this file. This file is caching data for your report when viewing.

Note:Issue is with caching.

[image]

Comment: I think,  it's "refresh" Problem. Can I do auto refresh while preview on dev PC?  Is it that,  this will get automatically refreshed on report server?

Comment: Yes it’s your local visual studio preview issue. Deploy this to your report server and it will get auto refresh every time.

Comment: Ok. Thanks.  Let me try and see how it works on report server.